# NSTable DidAddRowView and Alternating Background Colors

Tags: swift, nstableview

Perhaps someone can help me with this inquiry.  I have been struggling along with creating a NSTable with alternating background colors for the rows, and have settled on using code (obviously truncated), like so;

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, didAddRowView rowView: NSTableRowView, forRow row: Int) {
    print(row)

    rowView.backgroundColor = NSColor(white: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
}
```

The output of the print statement indicates that all rows (there are 17 of them) are being seen, but only the **last** row has the background color set like so.  I have attempted to do something like;

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, didAddRowView rowView: NSTableRowView, forRow row: Int) {

   if(row % 4 == 1) {
      rowView.backgroundColor = NSColor(white: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
   }
}
```

expecting that every fourth row, starting with row index 1, will have a white background color.  However, this does not seem to work.  More specifically, no rows have the adjusted (white) background color, and default back to the color set in IB.  Would it not be possible to change the row color in an alternating manner like this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well here is how it's working for me (I changed the colour of the cell in IB to show that the white colour defined works):

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate {

    let data = ["hello", "aloha", "bonjour", "ahoy!", "konnichiwa", "salut", "hallo", "yo", "hey", "wasup", "..."]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func numberOfRowsInTableView(tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
        var cellView = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier("cell", owner: self) as! NSTableCellView
        cellView.textField!.stringValue = data[row]
        return cellView
    }

    func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, didAddRowView rowView: NSTableRowView, forRow row: Int) {
        if(row % 4 == 1) {
            rowView.backgroundColor = NSColor(white: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        }
    }

    override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response!  It's so bizarre, I have nearly identical code, yet I cannot seem to get anything but the last row to have its background color changed.  I'm starting to think that maybe something in IB is awry...

Comment: Hmm perhaps check your connections coming from the table - I've only got two: dataSource and delegate.

Comment: Likewise!  And the table itself is working fine otherwise.  I'm going to try to use your code to build a new table and see if it works.  I'll let you know!

Comment: I created a new project using your code and was able to accomplish the same results as you.  Your code works perfectly.  The issue in my project appears to have been some conflicting code and settings in Interface Builder where I was setting a custom background color.  When I removed the code, your answer worked perfectly.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your code into `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.
e.g.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel!.text = yourData[indexPath.row]

    if indexPath.row%4 == 1 {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    }

    return cell 
}
```

Comment: I believe this will only work for a UITableView.  My Mac app (NSTableView) does not seem to accept any of the _UI_ references.

Comment: Oh sorry, I read your question wrongly. I did however set up an NSTableView in an OS X app and it works fine for me doing it your way